# bootstrap 3 navbar item width not consistent on Android Chrome and Opera Browser

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap, android-browser

I have created a website using bootstrap 3. I have noticed that the navbar item width is not consistent in Android Browsers. When viewed in Android Chrome or Opera Browser, the navbar item width is shorter, causing the text and caret to wrap to the next line.

The navbar rendered correctly in desktop browsers, iOS Safari and Android Firefox browser.

Please click on the link to view the screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvnXz.png

The link to the website is: http://new.pathlight.org.sg

Appreciate anyone's help on this and thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Not sure how you are getting the full menu to show in Android as it's responsive?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for responding. Full menu will show on 12" tablet devices that supports higher resolution eg: Samsung Note Pro.

Comment: Bootstrap v3 doesn't support Presto-based Opera.